# angular 2 access child component property from parent component

Tags: typescript, angular

Need to access to property children element.
Parent:

```
<div>
   <shipment-detail #myCarousel ></shipment-detail>
</div>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: "testProject",
  templateUrl: "app/partials/Main.html",
  directives: [ShipmentDetail] })
class AppComponent { 
  getChildrenProperty() {
  // I want to get access to "shipment" 
  }
}
```

Children:

```
@Component({
  selector: "shipment-detail",
}) 
export class ShipmentDetail  {
  shipment: Shipment;
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

See the [Component Interaction cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child). So, use @ViewChild() and add a method to ShipmentDetail that the parent can call to retrieve the shipment value, or just access the property directly, as I show below (because I was lazy and didn't want to write an API/method):

```
@Component({
  selector: "testProject",
  templateUrl: "app/partials/Main.html",
  directives: [ShipmentDetail] 
})
export class AppComponent { 
  @ViewChild(ShipmentDetail) shipmentDetail:ShipmentDetail;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.getChildProperty();
  }
  getChildProperty() {
     console.log(this.shipmentDetail.shipment);
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MT5mO5MV0CVRBK96Ypp9?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Great, Thanks for the solution ... one tip (for beginners like me) as i faced it ... accessing the property inside `constructor` it will give a runtime error, so `ngAfterViewInit()` is not a random choice.

Comment: In RC6 directives is deprecated , so you just need to remove directives : [ShipmentDetails]

Comment: It seems there is an interesting question, how could it be done in this week.

Comment: @Karthikv_26, see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild

Comment: @MarkRajcok don't seem to bw woking for angular 5

Comment: I have added an answer for new version of Angular

Answer (score 14):

In the new version of Angular, we can access child methods or property by importing child component in parent component:

Child component - shipmentdetail.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: "shipment-detail",
}) 
export class ShipmentDetailComponent implements OnInit  {
  shipment: Shipment;
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { ShipmentDetailComponent}  from './shipmentdetail.component';   
@Component({
  selector: "testProject",
  templateUrl: "app/partials/Main.html"
})
export class AppComponent { 
  @ViewChild(ShipmentDetailComponent) shipmentDetail:ShipmentDetailComponent;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.getChildProperty();
  }
  getChildProperty() {
     console.log(this.shipmentDetail.shipment);
  }
}
```

Check documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild