# angular 2 Access child component object from parent component class

Tags: angular, typescript

Need to access to property children element.

Parent:

```
<div>
   <shipment-detail #myCarousel ></shipment-detail>
</div>

@Component({
  selector: "testProject",
  templateUrl: "app/partials/Main.html")
class AppComponent { 
  getChildrenProperty() {
  // I want to get access to "shipment" 
  }
}
```

Children:

```
@Component({
      selector: "shipment-detail",
    }) 
    export class ShipmentDetail  {
      shipment: Shipment;
    }
```

Comment: Edit tag to angular instead of angularjs

Comment: **Exact** duplicate of [angular 2 access child component property from parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628161/angular-2-access-child-component-property-from-parent-component)

Comment: The answer over there does not work anymore as angular is updated and i tried to ask it with a commen which didnt help..

Answer (score 4):

The `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren` decorators provide access to the class of child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: "testProject",
    templateUrl: "app/partials/Main.html")
class AppComponent {

    @ViewChild(ShipmentDetail) ShipDetails: ShipmentDetail;

    getChildrenProperty() {
        console.log(this.ShipDetails.shipment);
    }
}
```

`@ViewChild` requires the name of child component class as its input and finds its selector in the parent component.

In your case it should be `ShipmentDetail`.