# How Can I Get An Instance of a ChartJS Bar Chart Using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I am using the code below to add a numeric value to the top of the a chartJS bar chart. Using Angular/Typescript, how can update my code to get an instance of the bar chart, and accomplish the same goal without using the animation property.

I have tried using @ViewChild, in the code below. I was able to get the context of the chart, but I wasn't able to access an instance of the chart, with the rendered data. What steps am I missing?

```
@ViewChild('baseChart') myChart: ElementRef;
private context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.context = (this.myChart.nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext('2d');
}




this.chartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: (tooltipItem: ChartTooltipItem, data: ChartData) => {;
                return labelCallback(tooltipItem, data);
            }
        },
        caretPadding: 17
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            ticks: {
                // sets the Y Axis legends
                callback(label: number): string {
                    return ticksCallback(label, sizes, locale, getSeparator);
                }
            }
        }]
    },
animation: {
    duration: 0,
    // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
    onComplete: function(chart: any) {
            const chartInstance = this.chart;
            const ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

          ctx.textAlign = 'center';
          ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
          this.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
            const meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
            meta.data.forEach((bar, index) => {
              if (dataset.data[index] > 0) {
                const revenueValue = dataset.tooltip[index];
                ctx.font = "normal 1.2rem Lato";
                // ctx.fillStyle = dataset.backgroundColor;
                ctx.fillText(revenueValue, bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
              }
            });
          });
        }
}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your chart component where you call new Chart() you have to put it in a variable (`this.chart = new Chart()`) and then access that from your parent component as described in this thread: [angular 2 access child component property from parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628161/angular-2-access-child-component-property-from-parent-component/51647163)