# Input decorator is not working in Angular( Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor. )

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

I have added input decorator in child component ts file and I am trying to access it from app component(parent), but I am not getting it.Error :  Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Hellocomponent.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hello.component.scss']
})

export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name:string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

appcomponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  styles: [`
 /* p{color: blue;}*/
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular';
  counter = 0;
}
```

App component.html

```
<h1>@Input</h1>
<app-hello [name]="title"></app-hello>
```

Comment: does this solve your issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874221/property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-constructor

Comment: @Input() decorator is used to pass data from parent to child, and you are trying the reverse.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628161/angular-2-access-child-component-property-from-parent-component) helps.